# Remove added backslash using he.decode (he library) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, decode

I'm using the the decode function from the the library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/he) to remove html entities from an api fetch. Everything works except that the decode adds two backslashes, one in front and one at the end of the string. I don’t quite understand why this happens. Any ideas how to get rid of this behavior?

Snippet of my code:

```
const resultAnswersCombined = resultNewAttribute.map(item => {
return {
  ...item,
  answers: [item.correct_answer, ...item.incorrect_answers],
  question: he.decode(item.question) 
}
})


question: he.decode(item.question)
```

gives me

```
question: "Who played Deputy Marshal Samuel Gerard in the 1993 
film \"The Fugitive\"?"
```

in the console.log.

```
question: item.question
```

gives me

```
question: "Who played Deputy Marshal Samuel Gerard in the 1993 
film &quot;The Fugitive&quot;?"
```

`Funny side-note: &#039; in questions is displayed correctly as '`

Comment: How exactly are you testing things to end up seeing backslash characters like that? The library does not do that when I try it, which makes sense because gratuitously adding the slashes would be an obvious bug.

Comment: You don't really need the `he` library now days. Or your using the wrong quotation characters.

Comment: @Pointy I'm seeing this behavior console logging the text one time with and one time without decoding it.

Comment: @Anuga Since I'm a beginner, how do you solve the problem without the he library?

Comment: Yea OK, I definitely do not see that. The code as posted looks like it's in a function; how is that function called? What happens to the returned value?

Comment: @Pointy I edit my post with an actual code snippet. Thanks for help

Comment: OK, thank you for the update. There are no backslash characters in your string. What you're seeing is the console itself telling you that there are quote characters in the string. It quotes them so that you can copy-paste the strings from the console view into JavaScript code, and you'll have a valid string constant.

Comment: You can try `item.question.indexOf("\\")` to look for instances of the backslash character in your string, and it'll tell you there aren't any. The console is designed to be helpful for debugging, and not to be a 100% faithful way of seeing the data in your live code.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, thank you, I will try it. Do you know any leaner way to solve this problem as Anuga mentioned before? If there is a “modern” solution how to replace the entities I would rather do it the right way. Regards!

Comment: I have no idea what @Anuga was talking about. If you're getting HTML entities from some source, and you don't want them, I don't see an alternative to using some library or tool or whatever to "fix" them.

Comment: For everybody out there: @Pointy was right.
I also recommend you this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
const text = he.decode("Tom&amp;Jerry");
const replaced = text.replaceAll('\\', '');
console.log(replaced);
return he.decode(replaced)
```

Or you can use

```
const replaced = text.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: This is correct, however the "he" package does not behave as the OP claims it does.